# "Не проинкасcированные" или "непроинкасcированные"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "не проинкасcированные" или "непроинкасcированные"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***не***проинка**сс**ированные, так как НЕ с одиночными причастиями пишется слитно. При наличии зависимых слов надо смотреть текст полностью.

Инкассо (итал. *incasso*) — посредническая банковская операция по передаче денежных средств от плательщика к получателю через банк с зачислением этих средств на счёт получателя.

Инкассация ― передачи денег инкассаторам.